# GREP command in loop

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have about 3000 files in a folder. My files have data as given below:

VISITERM_0 VISITERM_20 VISITERM_35 .....  and so on

Each files do not have the same values like as above. They vary from 0 till 99.

I want to find out how many files in the folder have each of the VISITERMS. For example, if VISITERM_0 is present in 300 files in the folder, then I need it to print

```
VISITERM_0  300
```

Similary if there are 1000 files that contain VISITERM_1, I need it to print
    VISITERM_1 1000

So, I want to print the VISITERMs and the number of files that have them starting from VISITERM_0 till VISITERM_99.

I made use of grep command which is

```
 grep VISITERM_0 * -l | wc -l
```

However, this is for a single term and I want to loop this from VISITERM_0 till VISITERM_99. Please helP!

Comment: It's unclear what you ask. Please reformulate your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
# ^^- the above is important; #!/bin/sh would allow only POSIX syntax

# use a C-style for loop, which is a bash extension
for ((i=0; i<100; i++)); do
  # Calculate number of matches...
  num_matches=$(find . -type f -exec grep -l -e "VISITERM_$i" '{}' + | wc -l)
  # ...and print the result.
  printf 'VISITERM_%d\t%d\n' "$i" "$num_matches"
done
```

Comment: ...then change your loop to start at 100 and proceed to 0, in the exact same way you would do so in C.

Comment: One more doubt. If I want to reorder the entire output in the descending order depending upon the number of file numbers, for instance: VISITERM_0 300, VISITERM_1 150, VISITERM_2 400 are the results and I need them to be organized as VISITERM_2 400, VISITERM_0 300, VISITERM_1 150, How can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `gnu awk` (gnu due to multiple characters in RS) that should do:

```
awk -v RS=" |\n" '{n=split($1,a,"VISITERM_");if (n==2 && a[2]<100) b[a[2]]++} END {for (i in b) print "VISITERM_"i,b[i]}' *
```

Example:

```
cat file1
VISITERM_0 VISITERM_320 VISITERM_35
```

```
cat file2
VISITERM_0 VISITERM_20 VISITERM_32
VISITERM_20 VISITERM_42 VISITERM_11
```

Gives:

```
awk -v RS=" |\n" '{n=split($1,a,"VISITERM_");if (n==2 && a[2]<100) b[a[2]]++} END {for (i in b) print "VISITERM_"i,b[i]}' file*
VISITERM_0 2
VISITERM_11 1
VISITERM_20 2
VISITERM_32 1
VISITERM_35 1
VISITERM_42 1
```

---

How it works:

```
awk -v RS=" |\n" '              # Set record selector to space or new line
    {n=split($1,a,"VISITERM_")  # Split record using "VISITERM_" as separator and store hits of split in "n"
    if (n==2 && a[2]<100)       # If "n" is "2" (does contain "ISITERM_") and has number less "100"
        b[a[2]]++}              # Count the hit of each number and stor it in array "b"
END {for (i in b)               # Walk trough array "b"
    print "VISITERM_"i,b[i]}    # Print the hits
' file*                         # Read the files
```

---

PS
If everything is only on one line, change to `RS=" "`. Then it should work on most `awk`